# How can I build the dev env and the prod env differently in build time? etc) db config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

i am using create-react-app, i should set the project prod env, dev env diffrently and deploy to dev server & prod server(seperated)

in now, i cant found the good way about this issue, i am changing myself config value before deploy to server(prod or dev). but it is 
inefficient and unstable.

for example)

//config.json

```
...
"db": {
    "prodSchema": "foo_p",
    "devSchema": "foo_d",
    "username": "dany",
    "password": "****",
    "host": "123.456.789.111:3306",
    "dialect": "mysql"
},
...
```

and use

//config use.js

in deploy, check & change...

```
//db.connect(config.prodSchema)
db.connect(config.devSchema)
```

i want get set way before 'yarn build' prod env & dev env differently in create-react-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using webpack you can apply the [environment plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/) and check for the environment variables to check which profile you should use.

browserify has a [transformation called envify](https://github.com/hughsk/envify) for the very same purpose.

then you can do something like this:

```
import axios from "axios";

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";

const config = {
  development: {
    baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
  },
  staging: {
    baseURL: "https://mysuperservice.herokuapp.com",
  },
  production: {
    baseURL: "https://mysuperservice.com",
  },
};
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: config[env].baseURL,
  headers: {
    "x-api-key": "ABC",
  },
});
```

Comment: oh, proccess.env.etc variable is work in react build?

Comment: they do, just set up your webpack or browserify and see.

Comment: can you see me example about the way??